# Best practice to handle data contract change in web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, datacontract

Assuming I have my car object in my web API like below:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Car")]
public class Car
{
    [DataMember]
    private string Model;
}
```

Then after the web API running for some time, I want to add one more filed into the car object like:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Car")]
public class Car
{
    [DataMember]
    private string Model;

    [DataMember]
    private int HorsePower;
}
```

But it sometimes cause break for the original client. I've searched on the internet and found that using API version and data contract version can solve this, with the below class definition, I can have my new version API operating on new version data contract.

```
[DataContract(Name = "Car")]
public class CarV1
{
    [DataMember]
    private string Model;
}

[DataContract(Name = "Car")]
public class CarV2
{
    [DataMember]
    private string Model;

    [DataMember]
    private int HorsePower;
}
```

But that seems not a very flexible approach, if the data contract evolves a lot, I would have a lot redundancy in my code and it is really hard to track so many versions.

Is there any better ways to handle this?